# How to set which solution when creating Entity definition using the WebAPI

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

**Context**

I would like to create a custom Entity using the Dynamics 365 WebAPI. When reading the official documentation [Create and update entity definitions using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593078.aspx) I can not find traces where to set which Solution is the target of the Entity Creation

**Question**

How and where to set in which Solution is the target the Create Entity operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that after creating the entity you could use the Web API's [Add Solution Component Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593057.aspx).

In [this article](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/wiki/Action-Examples), David Yack has an example of using this action to add a Web Resource to a Solution via his Web API helper library.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546.aspx#bkmk_componenttype) lists the component types. Entity is 1.